# Silverlight WebApp Calling Webservice in the same solution

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

I have a website solution that is composed of a Silverlight Project and an ASP Site that contains an asmx Webservice.
The Silverlight project calls various methods in the Webservice, and this works fine on my home PC.

When I publish the site (using 123-Reg if that makes a difference), it appears that the Silverlight app is no longer able to call the webservice. I have tried debugging the app by pointing my local version of the site to my published webservice and I get a "policy" issue.

I know that 123 Reg have .Net 3.5 running on their servers, so I would assume that the site should "just work" when I publish it. Am I making a hugely stupid assumption there? Is there anything that I can do to change the "policies" within my app? Or is there another way around what I am trying to do? I need to keep the webservice, as I want for it to be used from other places, and don't really want to duplicate code and create the same methods within the Silverlight project.

Thanks

Comment: What address do you have for your webservice in your *ServiceReferences.ClientConfig* file?

Comment: Have a look via fiddler and if it is a cross domain issue you will see a 404 error (which is most likely is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soundlike you are hitting a crossdomain issue, though you shouldn't really.

I would stick a clientaccesspolicy.xml in the root of you web server.
There are loads of questions on SO if you need examples or [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955(VS.95).aspx)